# Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've installed the stripe library with composer, and I have a problem that is only on one page (see picture here :

[image]

my code in cancelStripeSubscription.php :

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my key here");

$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($getSubId);
$sub->cancel();
```

I really don't understand why it's not working since it works in other files in the same directory.

error showing : "Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in D:\wamp64\www\etape4Prestige\"

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Are you using an autoloader?  You need some way to let one script know where another is located.  Many use autoloaders, or composer for dependency management.  Otherwise, you'll need to actually include the stripe files in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **autoloader** to actually **include the Stripe** classes...

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

This should do the trick if the library is installed with composer I guess...

Answer (score -1):

I have also installed and got the same error, You need to call stripe library like below by creating an object of Stripe not by scope resolution operator(::)

```
$stripe_obj = new Stripe();
$stripe = $stripe_obj->setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
```

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "scope resolution operator"?

Comment: I have installed the stripe and get same error when access setApiKey function through the Stripe directly with (scope resolution operator)::  but its gave me an error.

But when we create object and then access setApiKey it will work properly...

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it